# Angular 6 Authorization - UI permissions Vs API permissions

Tags: api, authorization, jwt, angular6

I am creating small Angular 6 application. 
  My Angular UI is showing data returning from Web API (2.0).
  I have implemented JWT Authentication.

Now I am implementing the Authorization in UI and API both. Like for every control in UI will have permission stored in database. Also for every action in API will have permission stored in database. One user will have all set of permission (UI permission + API permission).

For UI/API authorization I am using token to read permissions. In UI there is *ngIf check and in API there is custom fitler AuthorizeAttribute written to check the permission.

Please let me know the above approach is will be well suited for Angular + API environment ?

Answer (score 1):

For Angular front-end application control, use ngx-permissions package as it provides both role and permissions based control on each element/route. Permissions can be loaded in main app once and then html elements can have `*ngxPermissionsOnly="['permission-name']"` attribute. Similarly route control can be achieved using `NgxPermissionsGuard`.

For API access control, if application is using JAVA Spring Boot then `@PreAuthorize` annotation can be used for each REST end-point.